# Does one "drive" a motorcycle or "ride" it?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When you are the one steering the motorbike/motorcycle, are you driving the motorcycle, or riding the motorcycle?

I am asking because someone tried to correct my status update. Here's my status and the comment:

> Today, after 6 years, I drove a motorcycle on a long route. Great Feeling. Loved it!
>
> **Comment:** you don't drive a bicycle or motocycle... You ride a motorcycle... You drive a car...

Is that right?

Comment: Related: [Can “drive someone home” be used when the vehicle is a motorbike?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/)

Comment: Just thought I'd add a 'side note' that while one would drive a car and ride a motorcycle, the experience of controlling a **trike** is so much more like a car than a bike that I'd call it *'driving* a trike'.

Comment: Looking at the American corpus, '*drive* a motorcycle' has 5 hits, '*ride*' has 26. *Ride* seems to be the more standard usage.

Comment: Related : https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/83931/why-do-we-say-we-ride-and-not-drive-bicycles  The same question from the POV of Cyclists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are *driving* the motorcycle you are *riding* it. If you are on the back while someone else is driving it, you are riding *on* it.

Comment: Hmmm... I would say the passenger is *riding pillion* and call the  person riding the bike the *rider*.

Comment: +1 - But you could call out the difference more, I misread your answer the first time.

Comment: Does the first sentence of your answer mean that "driving a motorcycle" is wrong while "riding a motorcycle" is correct, or that both of them are equally acceptable?

Comment: @MrReality: They are equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

The terminology is left over from the days before motorized conveyances, where to "drive" horses or cattle was to induce them to move in a desired direction. People "rode" horses by sitting on them. People "drove" carriages by inducing the horses pulling them to move. People "rode in" carriages or "rode on" wagons when they weren't the driver.

So now,

- if something is a one-person mechanical conveyance you sit on, like a horse, you "ride" it.
- if something looks more like a carriage than a horse, you "drive" it.
- If something looks more like a carriage than a horse, and you are not controlling it, you "ride in" or "ride on" it (depending on whether you are inside or outside).

If elephants (which more than one person can ride) had been more common in England, we might "ride" rather than "drive" cars.

Comment: How do you explain "ride a train"?

Answer (score 8):

*Ride* means, as reported by the NOAD and the OED, *sit on and control a bicycle or motorcycle for recreation or as a means of transport*; it also means *sit on and control the movement of an animal, especially a horse*.

> Diana went to watch him ride his horse.

> She rode a Harley Davidson across the U.S.

Comment: Technically, _ride_ does not necessarily imply control as you can simply sit there and let something else do the controlling. But otherwise yeah, this is accurate.

Comment: Ride *does* imply control if you are known to be alone on the conveyance (vehicle or animal).

Comment: Not necessarily. You can ride a bucking horse or ride a train. You can ride a roller coaster too.

Answer (score 8):

A bike is **ridden**. Please see [Google NGrams Viewer for some empirical evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ride%20a%20bike,%20drive%20a%20bike&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

I caution against using "drive motorcycle" as a search term because, while hugely prevalent, it refers not to the action but to the type of drive-train.

Additionally: a horse is *ridden* when atop it but *driven* when behind it (as with a carriage or a plough horse).

Comment: The last para. is interesting to me, since it vaguely reflects my comment about trikes.

Comment: This ngram result is mostly irrelevant. "Bikes" first and foremost are BICYCLES, only secondarily motorcycles. So of course the result is heavily skewed in favor of "ride a bike"

Comment: According to Lexico, to drive is too "operate a **motor** vehicle". The OP's confusion is perfectly understandable because motorbikes are motor vehicles. Non-electric bicycles aren't, so it might not be appropriate to say "drive a bike", which could explain your skewed ngram result.

Answer (score 3):

I would say ride/rode a motorcycle.
Unless you were making a deliberate point about a car alternative = "I don't drive a car I drive a motorbike"

Answer (score 2):

I would use "drive" to describe operating most machines or motorized vehicles. You can drive a car, bus, truck, motorcycle, tractor. "Ride" would be necessary for bicycles, horses, donkeys and very large dogs.

That being said, the term "cattle drive" is a good example of the word's usage aside from the riding/driving meaning.

Comment: The reason one "rides" a motorcycle instead of "driving" it because of the seating position; in the case of bicycles and motorcycles, one sits astride them, as with horses, hence "ride."

Comment: Sure, but you still drive a motorcycle.

Comment: This is something that doesn't seem to be even remotely disputable. No native speaker of English would say "drive a motorcycle."

Comment: @The Raven: I don't understand the problem here: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22drive+a+motorcycle%22); [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=drive+a+motorcycle%2Cride+a+motorcycle&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). "Ride" is significantly more common but "drive" works just fine.

Comment: @Raven [Really?](http://www.dmv.org/va-virginia/motorcycle-license.php) What makes you say that?

Comment: @HaL and MrHen: The NGram evidence shows the dominance of the idiom "to ride" in this case. But HaL's DMV link shows something about the difference between "drive" and "ride" - there is probably some kind of rule governing it.

Comment: @The Raven: Does "ride" dominate usage? Sure. Do native speakers use "drive"? Yes. One note: Both driver and rider can "ride" but only one can "drive." It isn't surprising that "ride" is higher. The following context should also make sense: "Hank and I rode the bike into town. He drove."

Comment: @HaL perhaps there is UK/US divergence here.  I can't see any reference to 'motorcycle driving' in the UK literature.

Comment: @z7sg: Searching Google.uk finds similar references to driving schools or how-tos. [1](http://www.motorcycles2hire.co.uk/hiring_bikes/tips_on_driving_a_motorcycle_safely_and_responsibly.php) & [2](http://www.driving-school.co.uk/driving-a-motorcycle/) are two examples from .uk websites. I cannot really speak for UK usage, naturally, so your point could be completely valid with me having simply found a few outliers.

Comment: @MrHen Well OK, you do have a point, and perhaps it is indeed acceptable in common usage, but it really grates for me!  Certainly in the [official literature](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Highwaycode/DG_069867) they studiously avoid using the verb *drive* for motorcylists.

Comment: What's most likely the case is that to the ear, some uses of "ride" with respect to vehicles like motorcycles and jet skis, that one sits astride, is most natural - particularly to owners of said vehicles. "I rode my Harley all the way to Chicago" is idiomatic. Likewise "He rides a motorcycle to work" is almost the only possible expression. "Drive" sounds exceedingly weird in such cases. But "drive" may be possible when the emphasis is on operation particulars, like, "Motorcycles should drive on the left." No hard and fast rule here, but it's something like that.

Comment: @z7sg Interesting. After a bit of Googling I did find that UK references always used _riding_ on bikes or motorcycles and _driving_ for cars, while US usage is split almost evenly between _riding_ and _driving_ with no objective distinction. I'd always assumed that one simply rides on a motorcycle as they are driving it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the context of what you are saying.

If you need to state that

`there is something funny about the way he is riding the motorbike`

it is different than saying

`there is something funny about the way he is driving the motorbike`

or

where riding indicates the activity of sitting on, and driving indicates the activity of pushing forwards.

So... were you sitting on the motorbike whilst it was taking you for a ride? or were you pushing that motorbike around like a slave of your will?