# Why ride? Over ride or pilot?

Tags: grammar, verbs

- Why do you ride a horse and a bike, rather than drive it?
- Why do you pilot a plane, rather than drive it?
- Why do you drive a car, rather than pilot it?

You can go for a ride in a car, but only if you're not the one driving it. As you ride a horse, does that mean the horse it really in charge? Follow that logic to riding a bike, does that mean the bike is in charge?

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason as why we say _strong coffee_ and not _powerful coffee_? Or for that matter, why say _head ache_ and not _head pain_?

Comment: @Prasad, are you implying that English is less than logical?

Comment: Let's take a ride in my car. One of us will certainly drive it

Comment: Let's traverse that bridge when we come to it :)

Comment: @Edwin, in comparison to languages like Hindi? I dare say, yes, English seems less logical. In Hindi, the verb _chalaana_ (which means to drive in the context of vehicles), can be used for all transport vehicles including planes and ships.

Comment: I am going to go for a ride.  Alone.

Comment: Because, before there were internal combustion engines, people ***rode*** horses, ***drove*** carriages, and ***piloted*** ships.

Comment: Why is the guy who steers the submarine called the driver?  Why do we drive cattle, when we could ride them?

Comment: @mplungjan What? You don't have a chauffeur?

Comment: Interestingly, when you are controlling the tiller on a small sailboat, you are often said to be *driving* (at least in the US). *Piloting* is also used.

Comment: @PeterShor +1 But why did people ride horses, drove carriages and piloted ships? The essential question stays. So this is no answer :)

Comment: Peter Bridger, interesting question indeed. Have you made an effort to find an answer? Or to check if it has been asked earlier anywhere by anyone? Let us know.

Comment: @Kris: you have to look at the etymologies. For example, *pilot* comes from the Greek word *pedon*, meaning *steering oar*. The word *drive* for carriages came from the fact that you drove the horses that pull the carriage; it's the same root as the cattle *drives* they had in the Old West.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21073/6006

Comment: Also related - a similar question but from the Cyclist's point of view.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/83931/why-do-we-say-we-ride-and-not-drive-bicycles

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the definitions of **ride** and **drive**:

> [drive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drive) —
>
> 1. to cause and guide the movement of (a vehicle, an animal, etc.): to drive a car; to drive a mule.
> 2. to convey in a vehicle: She drove them to the station.
>
> ---
>
> [ride](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ride) —
>
> 1. to sit on and manage a horse or other animal in motion; be carried on the back of an animal.
> 2. to be borne along on or in a vehicle or other kind of conveyance.

This doesn't really provide an answer aside from, "because that's how we do it." The two distinctions you called out aren't even the weird ones:

- You can drive a mule but only without sitting on it. (If you sit on it, that's riding.)
- You can ride an animal while someone else drives it (from the ground).
- You can drive animals while riding on a different animal.

As far as vehicles, the distinction is usually how you position your legs.

- You *ride on* bicycles, motorcycles, all-terrain vehicles, rockets, railings
- You *ride in* cars, trucks, side-cars attached to motorcycles, shopping carts
- You *drive* cars, trucks, tanks and most other things you ride *in* (as long as you have control; so you don't really drive a shopping cart.)

**Pilot** is simply reserved for airplanes (airships), ships, spaceships and so on:

> [pilot](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pilot?s=t) — a person who steers a ship.

A more modern complication is what you call controlling a vehicle without being present:

- You drive an RC car
- You drive an RC *motorcycle*
- You pilot or guide a missile
- You merely fly an RC airplane

---

As with most issues surrounding terms like these, there is often debate about the appropriateness of one term over the other. The above is a good snapshot of opinions but you could spend quite a bit of time arguing for or against the particulars. The most debatable:

> I drive my motorcycle to work.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question, in one word, is idiom.  There may have been some distinction between *ride* and *drive* at some time in the past.  You certainly drive horses if you are controlling where they go without being on their backs, but the use of the "proper" word comes down to idiom.  If you are hospitalized in the US, you are "in the hospital;" if you are hospitalized in the UK, you are "in hospital."  Same illness, same facility.  Why the difference?  Idiom.

Comment: I thought that in the UK, you *queued up* to buy the tickets.

Comment: ... Unless you buy them online.

Comment: As I understand it, you have a choice.  Yikes!  I just ngramed and I may be wrong.

Comment: I've never heard 'stand on line', but am quite familiar with 'stand in line', and Oldham is in the UK.

Comment: I just blew it!  I should leave comments on the King's English to the King's subjects.

Comment: Peter Shor, you're right. In the UK, people would normally watch *film*, not a *movie*. Michael Owen Sartin seems confused.

Comment: As I understand it, people only *"stand on line"* in New York City and its surroundings.

Comment: You get hospital*ised* in the UK if you use **ize**!